# UIImagePNGRepresentation returns nil after CIFilter

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image

Running into a problem getting a PNG representation for a UIImage after having rotated it with CIAffineTransform.  First, I have a category on UIImage that rotates an image 90 degrees clockwise.  It seems to work correctly when I display the rotated image in a UIImageView.

```
-(UIImage *)cwRotatedRepresentation
{
    // Not very precise, stop yelling at me.
    CGAffineTransform xfrm=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(6.28 / 4.0));
    CIContext *context=[CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *inputImage=[CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
    CIFilter *filter=[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform"];
    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [filter setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&xfrm objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)] forKey:@"inputTransform"];

    CIImage *result=[filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    CGImageRef cgImage=[context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:result];
```

}

However, when I try to actually get a PNG for the newly rotated image, UIImagePNGRepresentation returns nil.

```
-(NSData *)getPNG
{
    UIImage *myImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"canada"];
    myImg=[myImg cwRotatedRepresentation];
    NSData *d=UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImg);

    // d == nil :(
    return d;
}
```

Is core image overwriting the PNG headers or something?  Is there a way around this behavior, or a better means of achieving the desired result of a PNG representation of a UIImage rotated 90 degrees clockwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yelling, but -M_PI_4 will give you the constant you want with maximum precision :)

The only other thing that I see is you probably want to be using [result extent] instead of [inputImage extent] unless your image is known square.

Not sure how that would cause UIImagePNGRepresentation to fail though.  One other thought... you create a CGImage and then use the CIImage in the UIImage, perhaps using initWithCGImage would give better results.

Comment: Looks like using the CGImage rather than the CIImage was the ticket.  And I've increased the precision.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: There is some problem with UIImagePNGRepresentation and CIImage. After migrating my code to use CGImage is worked fine.